# How do I delete a folders that match pattern in phing

Tags: phing

I have a build_ folders in my directory like build_10320 or build_10321. 
I need to write a target clean that deletes such a folder.

I am trying doing this

```
   <target name="clean">
        <echo msg="clean directory ./build_" />
        <delete includeemptydirs="true" verbose="true" failonerror="false" >
            <fileset dir="./">
                <include name="./build_*" />
            </fileset>
        </delete>
    </target>
```

But this doesn't work. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Phing still doesn't have the `<dirset>` feature working (which would be the natural choice). You can however make this work using `<exec>` & the relevant command for deleting files from your operating system.

For linux:

```
<exec command = "rm -rf ./build_*" passthru = "true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A `<fileset>` returns, as the name suggests, only files.

There is an undocumented `<dirset>` type that unfortunately cannot be used with `<delete>` [at the moment](http://www.phing.info/trac/ticket/1026).

Answer (score 0):

With Phing 3.x you can use `<dirset>` inside the `<delete>` task.

```
    <project name="delete-with-dirset" default="clean" basedir=".">
        <target name="clean">
            <echo msg="clean directory ./build_" />
            <delete includeemptydirs="true" verbose="true" failonerror="false">
                <dirset dir="./">
                    <include name="./build_*" />
                </dirset>
            </delete>
        </target>
    </project>
```